# How to call css into div class inner div?

Tags: html, css

I am working in web scraping. Now i am scraping one website and load into my website its working fine. But i need to add css into one div. This div does not contain any `id or class`.

But my main div contain class. How can i css for my inner div

For example:

```
<div class="ct-ui-spinner-animation">
    <div>
            <div> <!-- I Want to call css in this div-->
                Sample
             </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am trying this ways

First try:

```
 .ct-ui-spinner-animation > div
   {
    color:#fff !important;
    }
```

Second try

```
.ct-ui-spinner-animation {
        color:#fff !important;
    }
```

But not applying css please guide me. How can i do it.

Comment: use pseudo selector nth child items http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Comment: Your first try was close, the > notation means direct child of. Thus, it would be applied to the outermost div. It might work fine if you do .ct-ui-spinner-animation > div > div.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code was almost there.

You need to use two [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
.ct-ui-spinner-animation > div > div
{
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

Notice this will be applied for **all** the *div* elements which are the grandchildren of any element with the *.ct-ui-spinner-animation* class.

Answer (score 3):

```
.ct-ui-spinner-animation > div > div
{
    //Styles
}
```

Comment: You're missing one > selector

Comment: I was targeting the child div of the div within the class ct-ui-spinner-animation

Comment: This selector will be applied on every div which is inside another div in .ct-ui-spinner-animation, even if there are 20 other elements between them in their hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for the help and new knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Can be like this:

```
.ct-ui-spinner-animation > div > div{
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CCnMe/

or

```
.ct-ui-spinner-animation div {
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CCnMe/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could give a look at the first-child CSS attribute

```
.ct-ui-spinner-animation:first-child {
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

Setting a specific class or id for your div is (very) slightly better for the performance too.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's two nodes down, you need to use "div" or * to in the middle.

```
.ct-ui-spinner-animation > * > div
/* or */
.ct-ui-spinner-animation > div > div
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this to access the second child div:

```
 .ct-ui-spinner-animation div div
   {
   //CSS goes here;
    }
```

Comment: You've missed a little. This selector will be applied on every div which is inside another div in .ct-ui-spinner-animation, even if there are 20 other elements between them in their hierarchy. Read about the [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)