# How to access child element of sibling of its parent in html by css

Tags: html, css, drupal

Can anyone tell how I can access a child element of an element which sibling of an element of parent of current attribute?

```
<div class="views-field views-field-field-mobile-service-new-image">
    <div class="field-content">
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="image1.png" width="55" height="55" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="views-field views-field-view-node">
    <span class="field-content">
        <a href="#" class="colorbox-node" data-inner-width="650" data-inner-height="450">
            <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="image2.png" width="55" height="55" alt="" />
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

how I can access image in other div on hover of class field-content which is child of first div

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198327/apply-css-style-to-a-nested-class-inside-div , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352367/how-to-call-css-into-div-class-inner-div, these links may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Is it like, when you hover on image of one div at that time the second div image should be replaced by the first div's img?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you well, you can't do this with the CSS, but you can do it with JS, smth like that:

```
    $('.views-field-view-node img').hover(function() {
        var $yourImage = $(this).closest('.views-field-view-node')
            .parent().find('.views-field-field-mobile-service-new-image img').addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        var $yourImage = $(this).closest('.views-field-view-node')
            .parent().find('.views-field-field-mobile-service-new-image img').removeClass('hover');
    });
```

It's only example, you can improve my code and make it better, if you want.